# How to Import Self-Signed certificate into headless-Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, self-signed, firefox-headless

### Question

I want to access some websites using selenium(Python) and headless-firefox with Self-Signed certificate.

When I use FireFox Browser instead of selenium and headless-firefox, I could realize this as the following:

1. prepare Self-Signed certificate
2. Import it intor FireFox Browser like [this](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Adapter-for-SAP-Landscape-Management/2.1.0/Installation-and-Administration-Guide-for-VLA-Administrators/GUID-0CED691F-79D3-43A4-B90D-CD97650C13A0.html)
3. access websites using imported Self-Signed certificate

I want to do the same thing using headless-firefox and even using selenium(Python), but I have no idea.

Can anyone teach me  if this is possible and if so, how?

### Additional Information

- headless firefox: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/117.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-117.0.tar.bz2
- selenium: 3.141.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself.

To realize this, we can use [policies.json](https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates/#certificates)

Create a file named `/opt/firefox/distribution/policies.json` in the Firefox installation directory (eg. `/opt/firefox`).
The directory depends on OS

```json
// policies.json
{
"policies": {
"Certificates": {
    "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
    "Install" [
               "usr/local/share/ca-certificates/your.crt" // path of self-signed certificate
               ]
         }
    }
}
```